# Codesys Build Messages Empty

Tags: codesys

I have a strange problem, Hopefully an easy one.
I am not getting any Build Messages logged in Codesys 3.5 SP19 Patch 2.
After a Build, I show 3 errors, but no messages as to the content
The errors i can fix as i know the cause. my concern is the last of reports and how do i find other errors.
I can only guess its a setting somewhere that has got messed up, but i can't find anything.

I have searched the Doc's and PLC / IDE Options can't find any options that control the log level of the build process

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding

Comment: Tried that many times

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem, thinking it was a bug... There is a combobox in the messages section, it seems to work like a filter and sometimes it is selecting a type, but the error counter shows the sum of all types. Try choosing another option to see if the error appears.

[image]

Comment: Combo box is empty, which is very strange.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?